# Content push for Newsstand in iOS 7.1 to change magazine cover suddenly not working in existing Newsstand App

Tags: push, ios7.1

We noticed that the silent content push messages that we are sending to update the magazine cover of our Newsstand App suddenly stopped working specifically in iOS 7.1.

I just did some testing sending the content push to the following devices:

- iOS-5.1.1 -> push received -> magazine cover updated -> OK
- iOS-7.0.6 -> push received -> magazine cover updated -> OK
- iOS-7.1 -> push never received -> NOK

However, if I send a push alert message to these devices, all alert messages are correctly received and shown, so I am sure that I am using the correct device tokens.

And this issue is on an existing App live in the App store, never having this issue before and it seems to be specific to iOS 7.1.

This is the content push message we are sending:

$payload = '{
 "aps" : 
  { 
   "content-available" : 1,
  } 
}';

Anybody else having the same problems specific in iOS 7.1?

Thx!

Answer (score 0):

I am having that issue also on 7.1 in development.  If connected to XCODE we see the method application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler invoked... ONCE we disconnect from Xcode... that method does NOT get called based on reviewing the console.

EDIT :: Today during testing against the sandbox environment with a iPhone on iOS7 7.1 (11D167) the content-available starting working ??  We are getting calls into didReceiveRemoteNotification fetchCompletionHandler: NOW, even when phone is NOT connected to XCode or anything.  Even if the Phone is Locked and Application is in the background... which is what we needed and very important.

Really odd... but we did find that the Manual Do Not Disturb was ON.. on this test phone.. not sure how that got on and if that was issue.  Make sure that is NOT ON.. otherwise you will not get any remoteNotification calls into your application.  We may have gotten off track with the other postings that content-available was broken on ios7.1.

If anyone knows anything else about this, please share.

Comment: I just checked, and in our case the Do Not Disturb is OFF. So not related to the issue mentioned by us in this post. The content-available: 1 is never received if our Newsstand App is killed by the user (by swiping it up from the running Apps list).

Answer (score 0):

From https://support.magplus.com/entries/84992596-About-Lower-Issue-Download-Counts-Since-iOS-7:

> **About Lower Issue Download Counts Since iOS 7**
>
> With the release of iOS 7, Apple changed the way Newsstand Push Notifications work, and it is a significant departure from how Newsstand Push Notifications were delivered with iOS 5 and iOS 6. With iOS 7, Apple attempted to change the way these notifications worked, primarily optimizing the mechanism for apps that receive e-mail and Twitter updates and notifications multiple times within a 24-hour period. Part of the problem with iOS 7 is that it is not clearly differentiating Newsstand Push Notifications (which initiate a background download of content) from standard Push Notifications (which just deliver text).
>
> A key change in iOS 7 is that if an app is killed manually by the end user, then the app simply does not receive Newsstand Push Notifications to automatically download new content in the background. Users manually kill an app by bringing up a screen of currently running apps and swiping one up to force it to quit. Apple views this scenario as one where the end user has made a conscious decision that they do not want the app running/performing background operations which consume battery life.

The two unique features of Newsstand Apps as promoted by Apple self in 2011, 2012 and 2013 (in WWDC video's about newsstand) were:

A - background download of new Magazines and 
B - changing the cover when a new Magazine is available and showing a badge.

Unfortunately, in the real world situation, since iOS 7, Apple has killed both these features. Content push messages needed for these two features don't work if the user has killed the Newsstand App. Which in real world situation will almost always be the case.

Suppose you have a Magazine that appears monthly. How big is te chance that the user will have your Newsstand App running all the time in the background? I think almost none...

Before iOS 7, this user could be notified via a content push message resulting in a badge and a new cover visible in the Newsstand.

Since iOS7, these features are gone in real world situations.

Result: much lower magazine views and downloads.

Thanks Apple!